# Type DocumentClient exist in both Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core and Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage, azure-cosmosdb-tables

I have installed NuGet package **Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table** in my existing project, then few errors occured like "*the type DocumentClient exist in both Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core Version 2.11.2.0 and Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client version 2.14.1.0 and the type UriFactory exist in both Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core Version 2.11.2.0 and Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client version 2.14.1.0*"

Previously i was using **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table**, but now I want to use **Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table**, but error occurs.

Any way to solve this issue ??

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your project has both the Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB package and it's pulling the Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table package, which [according to Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table), has a dependency on Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core:

[image]

Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB and Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core are both the SQL API SDK packages, one is for Net Framework applications and the other is the Net Standard version (can be used for Net Framework or Net Core projects).

Replacing your Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB nuget reference in the project with Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core (targeting the same version you already do) would solve this issue.